# Hide shopping cart if is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

For a few days in a row I've tried to find a solution to hide an entire section if my shopping cart is empty and only be shown when I add a new item in cart. Shop is made entirely with javascript and jQuery.
Down below I will put the code , even a small idea is good.

P.S: I need to hide  the div.

```js
            $(".add-to-cart").click(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
                var price = Number($(this).attr("data-price"));

                shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, price, 1);
                displayCart();
            });

            $("#clear-cart").click(function(event){
                shoppingCart.clearCart();
                displayCart();
            });

            function displayCart() {
                var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
                console.log(cartArray);
                var output = "";

                for (var i in cartArray) {
                    output += "<li>"
                        +cartArray[i].name
                        +" <input class='item-count' type='number' data-name='"
                        +cartArray[i].name
                        +"' value='"+cartArray[i].count+"' >"
                        +" x "+cartArray[i].price
                        +" = "+cartArray[i].total
                        +" <button class='plus-item' data-name='"
                        +cartArray[i].name+"'>+</button>"
                        +" <button class='subtract-item' data-name='"
                        +cartArray[i].name+"'>-</button>"
                        +" <button class='delete-item' data-name='"
                        +cartArray[i].name+"'>X</button>"
                        +"</li>";
                }

                $("#show-cart").html(output);
                $("#count-cart").html( shoppingCart.countCart() );
                $("#total-cart").html( shoppingCart.totalCart() );
            }

            $("#show-cart").on("click", ".delete-item", function(event){
                var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
                shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(name);
                displayCart();
            });

            $("#show-cart").on("click", ".subtract-item", function(event){
                var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
                shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(name);
                displayCart();
            });

            $("#show-cart").on("click", ".plus-item", function(event){
                var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
                shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name, 0, 1);
                displayCart();
            });

            $("#show-cart").on("change", ".item-count", function(event){
                var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
                var count = Number($(this).val());
                shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
                displayCart();
            });


            displayCart();
            
// Shopping Cart functions

var shoppingCart = (function () {
    // Private methods and properties
    var cart = [];

    function Item(name, price, count) {
        this.name = name
        this.price = price
        this.count = count
    }

    function saveCart() {
        localStorage.setItem("shoppingCart", JSON.stringify(cart));
    }

    function loadCart() {
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("shoppingCart"));
        if (cart === null) {
            cart = []
        }
    }

    loadCart();



    // Public methods and properties
    var obj = {};

    obj.addItemToCart = function (name, price, count) {
        for (var i in cart) {
            if (cart[i].name === name) {
                cart[i].count += count;
                saveCart();
                return;
            }
        }

        console.log("addItemToCart:", name, price, count);

        var item = new Item(name, price, count);
        cart.push(item);
        saveCart();
    };

    obj.setCountForItem = function (name, count) {
        for (var i in cart) {
            if (cart[i].name === name) {
                cart[i].count = count;
                break;
            }
        }
        saveCart();
    };


    obj.removeItemFromCart = function (name) { // Removes one item
        for (var i in cart) {
            if (cart[i].name === name) { // "3" === 3 false
                cart[i].count--; // cart[i].count --
                if (cart[i].count === 0) {
                    cart.splice(i, 1);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        saveCart();
    };


    obj.removeItemFromCartAll = function (name) { // removes all item name
        for (var i in cart) {
            if (cart[i].name === name) {
                cart.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        saveCart();
    };


    obj.clearCart = function () {
        cart = [];
        saveCart();
    }


    obj.countCart = function () { // -> return total count
        var totalCount = 0;
        for (var i in cart) {
            totalCount += cart[i].count;
        }

        return totalCount;
    };

    obj.totalCart = function () { // -> return total cost
        var totalCost = 0;
        for (var i in cart) {
            totalCost += cart[i].price * cart[i].count;
        }
        return totalCost.toFixed(2);
    };

    obj.listCart = function () { // -> array of Items
        var cartCopy = [];
        console.log("Listing cart");
        console.log(cart);
        for (var i in cart) {
            console.log(i);
            var item = cart[i];
            var itemCopy = {};
            for (var p in item) {
                itemCopy[p] = item[p];
            }
            itemCopy.total = (item.price * item.count).toFixed(2);
            cartCopy.push(itemCopy);
        }
        return cartCopy;
    };

    // ----------------------------
    return obj;
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
            <ul>
                <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-name="Apple" data-price="1.22">Apple $1.22</a></li>
                <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-name="Banana" data-price="1.33">Banana $1.33</a></li>
                <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-name="Shoe" data-price="22.33">Shoe $22.33</a></li>
                <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-name="Frisbee" data-price="5.22">Frisbee $5.22</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button id="clear-cart">Clear Cart</button>
        </div>


        <div>
            <ul id="show-cart">
                <li>???????</li>
            </ul>
            <div>You have <span id="count-cart">X</span> items in your cart</div>
            <div>Total Cart:$<span id="total-cart"></span></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the div, you will need to modify the displayCart() as below.

```
function displayCart() {
    var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
    console.log(cartArray);
    var output = "";
```

> ```
>     var divEl = $("#show-cart").parent();
>     if(cartArray.length > 0) {
> ```

```
        for (var i in cartArray) {
            output += "<li>"
                +cartArray[i].name
                +" <input class='item-count' type='number' data-name='"
                +cartArray[i].name
                +"' value='"+cartArray[i].count+"' >"
                +" x "+cartArray[i].price
                +" = "+cartArray[i].total
                +" <button class='plus-item' data-name='"
                +cartArray[i].name+"'>+</button>"
                +" <button class='subtract-item' data-name='"
                +cartArray[i].name+"'>-</button>"
                +" <button class='delete-item' data-name='"
                +cartArray[i].name+"'>X</button>"
                +"</li>";
        }
```

> ```
>         $(divEl).removeClass('hidden');
>     } else {
>         $(divEl).addClass('hidden');
>     }
> ```

```
    $("#show-cart").html(output);
    $("#count-cart").html( shoppingCart.countCart() );
    $("#total-cart").html( shoppingCart.totalCart() );
}
```

So that way it will show or hide the div depending on the size of the object.
Try and comment.

PS: hidden is a bootstrap class. You will need to include the bootstrap library. Or instead just add the css picked up from the  library if you don't need it entirely.

```
.hidden {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `length` of cart items as boolean for jQuery [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display)

```
let $cartList = $('#show-cart');
$cartList.parent().toggle( $cartList.children().length );
```

Comment: Like this it would only hide the ul and will never show it again, even if a product is in cart.

I've thinked even to check if cart array has elements in it and give style display none to the div above the ul entirely, but I couldn't find a good way to do that, not so advanced in this :(

Comment: You need to call  it whenever you add/remove to list